# removing duplicate elements of a list with nested lists inside lisp

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, duplicates, nested-lists

The function remove-duplicates in lisp only works for simple lists like (a b c d).
My question is that how I can remove duplicate elements from a list with nested lists inside it. So for example

I have a list with nested lists as follows: ( (0 1) (0 2) (0 1) (0 3) )

and I want to remove one of the (0 1) lists which is repeated twice inside the list above to get:

( (0 1) (0 2) (0 3) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give `:test #'equal`  to `remove-duplicates`, and it will do what you want.

As we see in [CLHS: Satisfying a Two-Argument Test](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/17_ba.htm), `:test` defaults to `#'eql` when not given, and two lists like `(0 1)` are not `eql` unless they are *the same list* (`eq`).

```
CL-USER> (remove-duplicates '((0 1) (0 2) (0 1) (0 3)) :test #'equal)
((0 2) (0 1) (0 3))
```